# How to use QEMU remotely

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I'm trying to use QEMU to install a virtual machine of Ubuntu 16.04 on my Ubuntu server. My server has no desktop and I work on it through ssh. So I need to be able to use QEMU remotely without desktop.

Here is what I've executed:

```
qemu-img create Ubuntu16.04.qcow2 5G
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom /home/me/ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso -hda Ubuntu16.04.qcow2 -boot d -net nic -net user -m 1024 -localtime - curses
```

However, after executing the commands above, I get such an output on my ssh-terminal:
[image]

It seems that it needs a desktop to continue, I'm not sure.

Also, I tried the commend:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom /home/me/ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso -hda Ubuntu16.04.qcow2 -boot d -net nic -net user -m 1024 -localtime -nographic
```

But it blocks here:

```
me@mymachine:~$ qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom /home/zyh/ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso -hda Ubuntu16.04.qcow2 -boot d -net nic -net user -m 1024 -localtime -nographic
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'Ubuntu16.04.qcow2' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
```

Comment: I would prefer xen or kvm than qemu.

Comment: Can't try it myself now, so just a comment: Doesn't `-display none`, or `-nographic`, or `-curses` work? See man page for details.

Comment: @dirkt I can't get it to work with those optoins. `-curses` gives exactly what the OP screenshoted, `-nographic` gives nothing on terminal, I believe due to missing `terminal=ttyS0` due to missing kernel CLI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108334/how-to-boot-and-install-the-ubuntu-server-image-on-qemu-nographic-without-the-g

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run QEMU remotely, your best option is to use its VNC support; this will disable its SDL window display, and allow you to connect to the graphical display remotely. Use the `-vnc` option with a target display (*e.g.* `-vnc :0` to listen on port 5900 and allow connections from anywhere). If you’re not using a US English keyboard, you’ll also need to specify the keyboard layout with the `-k` option.

This also works with KVM if you’d rather use that. (KVM uses QEMU for its I/O.) Xen supports VNC too.